# Getting an attribute via another attribute in XSL

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I stink at XSLT, so I'm not sure how to approach this... I'm getting a feed from the EQ2 database. The XML looks like this:

```
<guilds limit="1" returned="1">
  <guild accounts="3" alignment="0" dateformed="1127855265" guildid="111" guildstatus="0" id="1111111111" last_update="1326986410" level="11" name="MyGuild" version="1" world="Permafrost" worldid="202">
    <ranks>
      <rank id="0" name="Leader"/>
      <rank id="1" name="Senior Officer"/>
      <rank id="2" name="Officer"/>
      <rank id="3" name="Senior Member"/>
      <rank id="4" name="Member"/>
      <rank id="5" name="Junior Member"/>
      <rank id="6" name="Initiate"/>
      <rank id="7" name="Recruit"/>
    </ranks>
    <members>
      <member dbid="123456" rank="0" name="Dude1"/>
      <member dbid="123457" rank="1" name="Dude2"/>
      <member dbid="123458" rank="2" name="Dude3"/>
      <member dbid="123459" rank="4" name="Dude4"/>
      <member dbid="123460" rank="4" name="Dude5"/>
      <member dbid="123461" rank="4" name="Dude6"/>
    </members>
    <events/>
  </guild>
</guilds>
```

I'm trying to add the ranks into a table. The XSL (version 1) snippet for it is as follows, but adding the name from the rank isn't working properly - I know this part is wrong:

```
<xsl:value-of select="rank/rank[@id=1]/@name"/>
```

So, can I get some help making it work and maybe an idea of how to shorten it?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" version="4.0" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">

<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="eq2roster" align="center">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <td colspan="4" class="eq2CharacterHeader">Character</td>
   <td colspan="3" class="eq2TradeskillsHeader">Tradeskills</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="ForumCategoryHeader">
   <th class="eq2NameHeader">Name</th>
   <th class="eq2RankHeader">Rank</th>
   <th class="eq2ClassHeader">Class</th>
   <th class="eq2LevelHeader">Level</th>
   <th class="eq2ArtisanHeader">Artisan</th>
   <th class="eq2ArtisanLevelHeader">Level</th>
   <th class="eq2SecondaryHeader">Secondary</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <xsl:for-each select="guilds/guild/members/member">
   <xsl:if test="@id &gt; 1">
   <tr>
    <td class="eq2Name">
     <xsl:element name="a">
      <xsl:attribute name="href">
       <xsl:text>http://eq2players.station.sony.com/</xsl:text>
       <xsl:value-of select="concat(normalize-space(/guilds/guild/@world), '/')"/>
       <xsl:value-of select="concat(normalize-space(@name), '/')"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="target">
       <xsl:text>_blank</xsl:text>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(@name)"/>
     </xsl:element>
    </td>

    <xsl:element name="td">
     <xsl:attribute name="class">
      <xsl:text>eq2Rank eq2rank-</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="translate(normalize-space(guild/@rank),' ','')"/>
     </xsl:attribute>

       <xsl:choose>
         <xsl:when test="member/@rank = 1"><span class = "rank1"><xsl:value-of select="ranks/rank[@id=1]/@name"/></span></xsl:when>
         <xsl:when test="member/@rank = 2"><span class = "rank2"><xsl:value-of select="ranks/rank[@id=2]/@name"/></span></xsl:when>
         <xsl:when test="member/@rank = 3"><span class = "rank3"><xsl:value-of select="ranks/rank[@id=3]/@name"/></span></xsl:when>
         <xsl:when test="member/@rank = 4"><span class = "rank4"><xsl:value-of select="ranks/rank[@id=4]/@name"/></span></xsl:when>
         <xsl:when test="member/@rank = 5"><span class = "rank5"><xsl:value-of select="ranks/rank[@id=5]/@name"/></span></xsl:when>
         <xsl:when test="member/@rank = 6"><span class = "rank6"><xsl:value-of select="ranks/rank[@id=6]/@name"/></span></xsl:when>
         <xsl:when test="member/@rank = 7"><span class = "rank7"><xsl:value-of select="ranks/rank[@id=7]/@name"/></span></xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>

    </xsl:element>

    <xsl:element name="td">
     <xsl:attribute name="class">
      <xsl:text>eq2Class eq2</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="translate(normalize-space(type/@class),' ','')"/>
     </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:value-of select="type/@class"/>
    </xsl:element>

    <td class="eq2level"><xsl:value-of select="type/@level"/></td>

    <xsl:element name="td">
     <xsl:attribute name="class">
      <xsl:text>eq2ArtisanClass eq2</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="translate(normalize-space(tradeskills/tradeskill/@class),' ','')"/>
     </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:value-of select="tradeskills/tradeskill/@class"/>
    </xsl:element>

    <td class="eq2ArtisanLevel"><xsl:value-of select="tradeskills/tradeskill/@level"/></td>

    <xsl:element name="td">
     <xsl:attribute name="class">
      <xsl:text>eq2Secondary eq2</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="translate(normalize-space(secondarytradeskills/secondarytradeskill/@name),' ','')"/>
     </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:value-of select="secondarytradeskills/secondarytradeskill/@name"/>
    </xsl:element>

   </tr>
   </xsl:if>
  </xsl:for-each>
 </tbody>
</table>

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Context is everything; would it be possible to update the question with the entire `xsl:template`?

Comment: Please, provide the exact wanted output -- otherwise we have to be guessing -- which actually means this question sucks in its present state. Please, edit and improve.

Comment: @DevNull ok I've included the entire stylesheet

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev Here is the output I'm getting: http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/xe2sN/

Comment: Also here is the original XML feed: http://data.soe.com/xml/get/eq2/guild/?name=Ardent%20Regression&c:resolve=members%28displayname,type.class,type.level,type.race,type.deity,type.gender,guild.rank,guild.status,secondarytradeskills,tradeskills%29

Comment: I'll update based on the linked XML, which answers the final question in my post.

Comment: @fudgey: You misunderstood: We need the output that should be produced exactly from the provided XML document. The one at the provided link obviously isn't produced from the XML document you provided. If you have isolated the problem, you may give us a simplified and small XML document and also specify the exact output wanted. Then you can use the smaller scale solution for your real problem.

Comment: None of the `member` elements in the linked file actually have a `rank` attribute. I'll leave my answer alone instead of guessing. It should provide the way, anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following expression associates a `member` with its corresponding `rank` using `current()` (assuming that the context node is the `member` in question):

```
../../ranks/rank[@id=current()/@rank]/@name
```

Full example:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="member">
        <td class="eq2Rank eq2rank-{guild/@rank}">
            <span class="rank{@rank}">
                <xsl:value-of 
                    select="../../ranks/rank[@id=current()/@rank]/@name"/>
            </span>
        </td>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output (based on the originally posted sample XML):

```
<td class="eq2Rank eq2rank-">
   <span class="rank0">Leader</span>
</td>
<td class="eq2Rank eq2rank-">
   <span class="rank1">Senior Officer</span>
</td>
<td class="eq2Rank eq2rank-">
   <span class="rank2">Officer</span>
</td>
<td class="eq2Rank eq2rank-">
   <span class="rank4">Member</span>
</td>
<td class="eq2Rank eq2rank-">
   <span class="rank4">Member</span>
</td>
<td class="eq2Rank eq2rank-">
   <span class="rank4">Member</span>
</td>
```

Comment: Thanks, but the rank still isn't showing up... I've updated my question with the entire stylesheet and in the comments under my question I've included the HTML output in a jsFiddle

Comment: Did you notice that none of the `member` elements in the file you linked actually have a `rank` attribute?

Comment: If it should use the child `guild/@rank` then simply use `../../ranks/rank[@id=current()/guild/@rank]/@name`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you can do something like this but it might be worth a shot. In the context of a single member

```
<xsl:value = "//ranks/rank[@id = ./@rank]/@name"/>
```

It uses X-Path to jump to the top and look for the ranks node, find the rank element whose ID attribute equals the rank attribute of the member, and grabs the name attribute

It's been a few years since I had to XSL like that, but should allow you to get rid of the XSL:choose block

Comment: Sorry I forgot to include that the snippet I shared is inside of a for-each loop `<xsl:for-each select="guilds/guild/members/member">`. Anyway, as I said I suck as XSL and the code you shared gives an error - shouldn't that start with `<xsl:value-of select="`?

Comment: Yes it should be value of.  we're thinking the same thing (Context of a single member record)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure if I get the question.

Asume that you have the right rankid you probably want to use variable

```
<xsl:variable name="rank" select="translate(normalize-space(guild/@rank),' ','')"/>

<span class = "rank{$rank}"><xsl:value-of select="ranks/rank[@id = $rank]/@name"/></span>
```

Comment: Sorry I updated my question.. the snippet is wrapped in a for-each loop.